# Database connections with RDS not working after deploying

Tags: amazon-web-services, web-applications, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds

I have developed a Dynamic web App, which leverages Amazon RDS. Servlet talks with RDS fetches data and presents it using JSP. The process is working fine. Next, I uploaded the war file of project on AWS Elastic beanstalk. But Database connections are not working.

Could you please guide me here? Why my connection variables are not working after deploying?

I made few changes to the early deployment and now App takes forever to load.

Comment: After deploying the War file did your confirm the DB connection string is correct?

Comment: @error2007s What exactly do you mean if string is correct? I used a string to connect to a remote database(which was working) after deploying the the war file I believe there is no need to change the string. am I correct ?

Comment: @error2007s 'final String DB_URL="jdbc:mysql://proj2.crwqdxb9dkgh.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com/test";' This is the url DB

Comment: conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS); This is I am using to establish connection.

Comment: Any errors reported in the logs?

Comment: @Seva previous problem was solved. Now I am getting 502 error. I have popsted a question about it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38288966/getting-502-proxy-error-after-deploying-app-to-aws