# Getting 502 proxy error after deploying app to AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, proxy, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I deployed an Application to AWS elastic beanstalk. When I try to open the application, I am getting 502 proxy error Saying following message.

> Proxy Error
>
> The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
>   The proxy server could not handle the request GET /.
>
> Reason: Error reading from remote server
>
> Apache/2.2.31 (Amazon) Server at mehe.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com
>   Port 80

Strange part is when I run the application from localhost(Still connected to amazon database) the application is working fine, but after deloying it is not working. Here's the link to [application](http://mehe.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/)

Any ideas how to get rid off it.

Answer (score 1):

The timeout value for HTTPD is lower than the timeout value set for ELB.  Change the timeout value in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

The keep the value between reboots you'll need to either create a custom AMI or use [.ebextensions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions.html) feature.