# 502 proxy error on deploy to AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, proxy

Eclipse IDE used to create JSF web app that runs locally loading remote MySQL data.  But does not run when deployed to AWS.  What could cause the 502 proxy error?

[deployed will show error after showing LOADING...](http://35.167.46.75/faces/index.xhtml)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting 502 proxy error after deploying app to AWS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38288966/getting-502-proxy-error-after-deploying-app-to-aws)

Comment: How is this deployed (elastic beanstalk, raw ec2, etc.)?  What do your logs show?

Comment: @Mark B found a partial solution:

it is a time out issue, I finally found the logs on AWS.

Comment: @stdunbar found a partial solution:

it is a time out issue, I finally found the logs on AWS.

Answer (score 0):

The 502 error reports a PROXY error - INCORRECTLY, if you view your log, see my other post on how to access AWS beanstalk tomcat error logs, you shall see the error is really a TIME OUT issue which is resolved by creating a new conf file in your Project view these two links for the complete solution:
[AWS instructions from AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions.html)
[Solution here - on how to increase the time out in your application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25557874/elastic-beanstalk-deployment-taking-longer-than-timeout-period-how-do-i-increas)